# Removing duplicates in a dataset in python based on 2 columns simulataneously

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe and wish to remove rows based on whether either entries of 2 particular columns are duplicate or not, starting from the first row and proceeding downwards (keeping the first hit and removing the other duplicates).

For example starting from:

| Group_1 | Group_2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Blue | 90 |
| Red | Orange | 85 |
| Red | Violet | 82 |
| Green | Blue | 79 |
| Green | Yellow | 74 |

And having an output where all entries are unique (considering both columns simultaneously - the fourth row is removed because "Blue" in the second column is already present in the first row):

| Group_1 | Group_2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Blue | 90 |
| Green | Yellow | 74 |

Comment: Does `df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Group_1", "Group_2"])` do what you want?

Comment: No, because that only removes rows that are exactly identical to each other (ex. [Red, Blue] and [Red, Blue]) and still retain those which have one duplicate entry (ex. [Red, Blue] and [Red, Orange]).

Comment: Can you give an example that the proposed answer does not solve?

Comment: When using df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Group_1', 'Group_2']), the output is the whole dataframe again (given that no combination is exactly identical).                                        When using df[~(df.Group_1.duplicated() | df.Group_2.duplicated())], the output only retains the first row, because the columns are not considered together (first it removes duplicates from first col and then from second col).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any direct method for dropping duplicates in a col1 OR col2 manner instead of AND, but you can simply use a for loop to drop duplicates on the columns you want sequentially.

```
for col in ['Group_1', 'Group_2']:
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=col, inplace=True)
```

or

```
for col in df.columns[:2]:
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=col, inplace=True)
```

It also automatically keeps the first occurrence but you can specify it in the method:
`df.drop_duplicates(subset=col, inplace=True, keep='first')`

Comment: I think the result may depend on the order in which the two columns are considered. Another approach could be `df[~(df.Group_1.duplicated() | df.Group_2.duplicated())]`.

Comment: For the record, here is an example when order matters: `pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2], "B": [10, 20, 20]})`.

Comment: Good point, in that example mine first removes the second row, then keeps the third row as there is no longer a duplicate in the second column.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! However, when applied, I think that both methods are still considering the columns individually, rather than simultaneously row by row.